# Preserving array type if it is already known

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to make it so that if the type `number | number[]` is known it can be passed to a generic function which validates it is an array without losing the fact that the array type is `number[]`. Simplified example:

```
function assertArray(value: unknown): unknown[] {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  throw new Error();
}
```

Usage:

```
const value: number | number[] = [1, 2, 3];
const verified = assertArray(value);
```

In the example above I want `assertArray`'s return type to be smart enough to figure out it is returning `number[]` since it was passed `number | number[]` and made sure it was the only array option `number[]`. However, it is currently returning `unknown[]`. I want to do this while keeping the flexibility to pass in any kind of array to `assertArray` and have it return the right type of array if it can be determined.

Comment: @jcalz. This approach is interesting, but it should be able to work with cases like `const value: unknown = foo(); const verified = assertArray(value);` and know that `verified` is `unknown[]`. Instead it says it's `never`.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! The first option seems to be working well in all of my tests so far. I don't understand why it works though - paricularly the `unknown[] extends T ? unknown[]` part and why that's needed.

Comment: I'm writing up an answer now; please [edit] the question to demonstrate the use case where the input is of type `unknown`, since the comments here are ephemeral and may be deleted by mods at any time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) that happens when you use a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) is tricky to emulate.  And how far you want to go to achieve that really depends on your use cases.

Essentially when you want to narrow a type `T` to another type `U`, the compiler has to choose between filtering a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T` to those members assignable to `U` (i.e., [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)) , or [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `T` with `U` (i.e., `T & U`), or some combination of those.  Conceptually those should be similar, but practically speaking there are all kinds of observable differences.

In your case, if `U` is `unknown[]`, then this is what one might expect, and would happen with various basic approaches:

| `T` | expected | filter union | intersect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `number | number[]` | `number[]` | `number[]` | `number[] & unknown[]` |
| `unknown` | `unknown[]` | `never` | `unknown[]` |
| [`ArrayLike<string>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/250065e55b8f2bb212cb9d19b191cfeb15184ee0/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1545-L1548) | `string[]` | `never` | `ArrayLike<string> & unknown[]` |

(That `ArrayLike<T>` type just means it's a type with a numeric `length` property and a numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) so that you can read and write values of type `T` to any numeric-indexed property.  It's [array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#working_with_array-like_objects).)

It's clear that neither of the basic approaches works perfectly by itself.  That means we need something a little more complicated, and we still might not get exactly what we want.

---

Here's one possible way forward:

```
function assertArray<T extends unknown>(value: T) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value as
            T extends unknown[] ? T : (T & unknown[]);
    }
    throw new Error();
}
```

The return type is `T extends unknown[] ? T : T & unknown[]`, a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that filters unions, but instead of removing union members that don't match, it intersects these members with `unknown[]`.  That results in the following behavior:

| `T` | expected | return type of `assertArray()` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `number | number[]` | `number[]` | `number[]` |
| `unknown` | `unknown[]` | `unknown[]` |
| `ArrayLike<string>` | `string[]` | `ArrayLike<string> & unknown[]` |

So, that's pretty good, and the use cases mentioned in your question are covered.

It isn't *perfect* though, since one might hope that an `ArrayLike<string>` could be narrowed to `Array<string>` after a successful `Array.isArray(x)` call.  And intersections of arraylike types aren't always useful.  But it's what comes out of a type guard function of the form `x is unknown[]`, so maybe it's good enough!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVATgTxQewKJgFcAbEAFwgDkyC0QiBhbYUtbIgMSOwHcBBUIhigBLKEgDeAWABQSOUgBmBYPFLCmSEFCgQ0pXmloYAPCiQQAHuWAATMcoDWwHsAB8ACgBudAhABcqACUEjLyYUjCCkjuBkYAdKKxIBhePhCBwVKy4TloEKQ0wEjeRL6aUKE5VXJmltZ2SI7O3MAA2gC6SAD8qEgBZgBkjcBOLh0A3JU5AL5T4aQAFqzcSMAQK7iG2GjugZPZcrPSc-BMUKTFaQHABGAARrpIAD6rtw9oHUgAvEitAIwAGiQACYgQBmdr7MKnYDnYq6SLCCA2ABqaW+5R0eiSKRKvj2c08CIUSNRaTmAHoKUgAHpdGQnM4XTzAgJNFwYiaM2HM4mklHAjFaLH6QzJLzAgkHeFoRHIgWUil0hnHaUwuGeMEBHEAGWEDggxnOsuAAHNXJzIdyNZqhdpdKKjF4wVKwlSwsrVUcZKBILAEMhePa9OpgOxlKpQyFVWElCo1BphQ6calSv5hqMWoEAkm9GI8chRBnmm1OllqpFogBCHEJKApgsZJCLZardZITasHau+TetVMy5p65vR4vG73XSfH7-IGgpAQqHyXOO8WNxdyAuK2n0mPydXM1nFjnTq0HFVhZcNyXr4rAxWe63MrVIXX6w3G4Rmi0nm+XsW4l0b01e8dzmFU+yAA)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for pointing out the `ArrayLike` situation, which is not what I want, but good to know where the edge cases are. This is definitely something I can work with.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? --> [TSPlayground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoEEtbICeAPACoB8AFAG7IA2IGAXImQJStmIDeAsAChEwxDGCIq+QkQB0MVFOK0GTdu16CRWxFgxQQWJHUYYA3JpEBfC8KgALLHADuiMBhcBRAnCxV25gWsBQUEIBFQoVxAAWwBGVjAYgCNsRABeRAAWALCwCMQabDEYDAATWPSUdGw8AiVEuP8QgVz8hoAmBOTsAG0AXUqe2IAaRHbRgGY+nPDIwqxisvbKtEwcRSIqDqbgltmo6Imu6JSsfv7BodHxxCnp0P35xdKJler1us2GiZ2gA)

```ts
function assertArray<T>(value: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value;
    }
    throw new Error();
}


const num1: number = 4;
const verified1 = assertArray(num1);

const num2: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
const verified2 = assertArray(num2);

const num3: number[][] = [[1, 2, 3]];
const verified3 = assertArray(num3);
```

Comment: That works surprisingly well, but here's a case where it doesn't:

`const value: number[] | number[][] = [1, 2, 3][]; const verified = assertArray(value);`

`verified` should be `number[] | number[][]` here because it is only making sure it's an array and both types are arrays. But instead it says you can't even pass in `number[] | number[][]` to `assertArray`

Comment: @NathanWall `[1, 2, 3][]` is not a valid js syntax

Comment: Are you sure?  As @wonderflame mentioned that is not valid syntax at all.  See [this TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoEEtbICeAPACoB8AFAG7IA2IGAXImYgD5sDaAugJSsyfRAG8AsAChEMxDGCIq+QkQB0MVMuK0GTfvzFTZxxFgxQQWJHUYYA3EdkBfRzKgALLHADuiMBl8AUQI4LCp+B0kXSSkpCARUKEQbJlYwEABbACNsES507NzeEQBeRG4ARgAaRAAmGoBmYt5I+LBE5Ox5GAwAE0QytEwcLSIdWwipIA)

Comment: @ChrisBarr Sorry, I made the example in haste.  I meant `[[1, 2, 3]]`. Here's a [TSPlayground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoEEtbICeAPACoB8AFAG7IA2IGAXImYgD5sDaAugJSsyfRAG8AsAChEMxDGCIq+QkQB0MVMuK0GTfvzFTZxxFgxQQWJHUYYA3EdkBfRzKgALLHADuiMBl8AUQI4LCp+B0kXSSkpCARUKEQbJkQAXkRubgBGABpEACZ8gGZeXhRUPxAAWwAjbBEuMBr6rD4+SPiwROTseRgMABN0iswcLSIdWwipIA) that illustrates the problem I was trying to get across.

Comment: Ok, then just simplify it down to `T` as the only type. Whatever you put in is the type.  I've updated my answer and here's the [TSPlayground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoEEtbICeAPACoB8AFAG7IA2IGAXImQJStmIDeAsAChEwxDGCIq+QkQB0MVFOK0GTdu16CRWxFgxQQWJHUYYA3JpEBfC8KgALLHADuiMBhcBRAnCxV25gWsBQUEIBFQoVxAAWwBGVjAYgCNsRABeRAAWALCwCMQabDEYDAATWPSUdGw8AiVEuP8QgVz8hoAmBOTsAG0AXUqe2IAaRHbRgGY+nPDIwqxisvbKtEwcRSIqDqbgltmo6Imu6JSsfv7BodHxxCnp0P35xdKJler1us2GiZ2gA)